# Accessing a oauth2 secured service via WSO2 API Manager

Tags: spring-security, wso2, microservices

I have a project in which there are several microservices which are secured using spring oauth2.I have published these services on WSO2 API Manager and disabled the oauth2 feature of WSO2 as my services are already secured using spring oauth2.Now when I access my services published on WSO2, using token of spring oauth2 i get in response either status code 0 "no response" or status code 403 unauthorized.What could be the issue here.

Comment: what do you mean "disabled the oauth2 feature of WSO2"

Comment: It means I can access a published API without providing any Authorization token of the API Manager. I have selected x-auth-type as none on the Managed tab of API publisher in order to disable token based authorization of WSO2.

Answer (score 0):

The WSO2AM (API Manager) authorizes the clients using the OAuth protocol and the backend services should trust the WSO2AM providing service authorization.

The API MAnager is not able (by default) validate the tokens of your backend services.

As far I know WSO2 AM clears the "Authorization" header to the backend services. (correct me when I am wrong).

your options:

1. Setup a proper environment, where APIM is used to authorize users. The APIM can send a JWT token to the backend services with user identity and attributes and the backend service will validate and trust the APIM JWT token containing user identity and attributes. I really suggest you stick to the way how APIM works and not try to force it working other way
2. If you really must using your own OAuth tokens, you could send the authorization token in different header (which will not get cleared)
3. You could create a custom mediation flow to to re-enter the authorization header into the request (I am not sure if you will need to update the exposed api mediation flow too or not to skip the default authorizer).